# HAProxy dropping same HTTP resoponse 200OK everytime

Tags: http, haproxy

I would like to ask question and appreciate if someone can help me
to find solution.

I am using haproxy ver 1.4.15

```
[root@HAProxy tmp]# haproxy -v
HA-Proxy version 1.5.14 2015/07/02
Copyright 2000-2015 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>.
```

## Problem

However, I am having a problem that it is dropping same HTTP Response every time
and not forwarding back to the client.

When below two requests are sent to HA Proxy,
only the response of second one is sent back to the client.
For the first one , haproxy is receiving back from the backend but drops the 200 OK when it is forwarding to the client.

```
Oct 14 14:31:17 localhost haproxy[11601]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50114 [14/Oct/2015:14:31:17.193] http-in console/Console 0/0/0/22/25 200 78668 - - --NI 1/1/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /Console/MultiLanguageSvc?Domain=xxxx&SYS=Care&LatestTime=&SVC= HTTP/1.1"
Oct 14 14:31:19 localhost haproxy[11601]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50115 [14/Oct/2015:14:31:19.225] http-in console/Console 0/0/0/104/104 200 3948 - - --NI 1/1/0/1/0 0/0 "GET /Console/CareLoginSvc?AgentID=91007@xxxx&Password=8BA0FC9468973A97956AA849462406C2&ExtNo=7603&Lang=ja_JP&SVC= HTTP/1.1"
```

Debug log showed any sign of errors.

Below are the part of debug log results.

```
/usr/local/haproxy/sbin/haproxy -f /usr/local/haproxy/etc/haproxy.cfg -d -V
Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 3 (2 usable), will use epoll.
Using epoll() as the polling mechanism.

** Below are the 200OK that is not sent to the client.**
00000000:iconsole.srvrep[0008:0009]: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Cache-Control:
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Pragma:
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Content-Length: 78470
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 09:11:24 GMT
00000000:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Server: MMCC
00000001:http-in.clicls[0008:0009]
00000001:http-in.closed[0008:0009]

** Below are the 200OK that is sent to the client. **
00000002:iconsole.srvrep[0008:0009]: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Cache-Control:
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Pragma:
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Content-Length: 3751
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 09:11:26 GMT
00000002:iconsole.srvhdr[0008:0009]: Server: MMCC
00000005:http-in.clicls[0008:0009]
00000005:http-in.closed[0008:0009]
```

Does anybody have any guess why HA Proxy drops certain requests?

Comment: Seems very odd, Can you share your configuration file as well please?

Comment: Seems very odd, Can you share your configuration file as well please?